# R Shinydashboard Header Color

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am creating a dashboard that needs to adhere to corporate style requirements.  I need to alter the background color of the header.  I have successfully altered the color except for when I mouse over the header, it changes to a different color.

Here is an example of the header with the proper color scheme:

[image]

Here is the same dashboard with my mouse hovering over the header:

[image]

For added measure, here is the result of inspecting the element:

[image]

Any help that can point me in the right direction to keep the background of the header a white color would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adjusting the CSS that appears in a supporting CSS file.  In the OP, the inspect element tool points to a second CSS file that I had not altered.  Specifically, the all-skins.min.css file.

Once I located that file, which for R/shinydashboard, the file appears in the AdminLTE directory of the package library/shinydashboard, I found the element that affected the behavior:

`.skin-red .main-header .logo:hover{background-color: }`

Since I wanted the background color to remain white, even on hover, I inserted #FFF into the `background-color` element and, now, the background color for the header remains white even on hover.

Answer (score 1):

There will be an css property most likely .logo : active or something - remove this.

Would need full code to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Thank you @apple-key, your response pointed me in the right direction.  I'm going to post a complete answer for future readers.